# Remove duplicate words and keep only the longer entries

Tags: awk

I have a text file that has duplicate words. It is easy to sort and extract unique words. But some of the words has slash followed by a tag. In that case, I need to remove the words without slash and keep the longer word in the file.

For e.g. If the file looks like this...

```
test/e
this/x
word/p
and
some
more/q
test
this
and
some
```

Using sort:

```
sort -u  t1.txt
and
more/q
some
test
test/e
this
this/x
word/p
```

But the expected result:

```
and
more/q
some
test/e
this/x
word/p
```

---

Update:
I used over-simplified example. There are cases when a word may have multiple tags. In that case I need to keep those words.

```
# cat t1.txt
test/e
this/x
word/p
and
some
more/q
test
this
and
some
more/n
word/n

# awk -F/ '!seen[$1]++{rows[$0]} END {for (i in rows) print i}' t1.txt
some
test/e
more/q
and
word/p
this/x
```

In this case, **more/n and word/n** should be included in the output:

```
some
test/e
more/q
and
word/p
this/x
more/n 
word/n
```

---

Update2:

Is it possible to merge "word/n" and "word/p" to create a single entry "word/np" (or "word/pn")?

Comment: Could you please do confirm if longer words are always separated by `/`?

Comment: Yes. some words have tags. This is hunspell dictionary format.

Comment: Can you clarify why your output is not sorted anymore?

Comment: Don't show one set of input/output and then say "oh that's not right" and then a different set - just clean up your question to only show the example you want us to use and get rid of the example you don't want us to use so we don't waste time coming up with solutions to a problem different from the one you have.

Comment: .... and now I see you also have "Update2" where you want output that's in neither of your posted examples. Please clean up your question so it simply shows what you want and get rid of all the stuff you don't want.

Comment: @shantanuo the reason you associated with the bounty is `shantanuo is looking for a more detailed answer to this question.` but [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139150/shantanuo) `Bounty is for the help that you have already provided.` suggests the bounty is actually to reward an existing answer. Please be clear in your postings so multiple people don't waste time trying to help you with problems you don't have and/or when you already have an answer you've decided is the correct one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try the following:

```
awk '{
    sub("/.*$", "", prev)       # remove "tag" from the variable prev
    if ($0 != prev) print       # print $0 if it differs from prev
    prev = $0                   # update prev
}' < <(sort -r t1.txt)          # feed the reverse-sorted file
```

Output for the 2nd t1.txt:

```
word/p
word/n
this/x
test/e
some
more/q
more/n
and
```

**[Edit]**
If you want to extract `word` and `more` out of the output above, please feed the output to:

```
awk -F/ 'seen[$1]++ {print $1}'
```

Result:

```
word
more
```

**[Edit2]**
If the input file contains multiple tags, please try the following:

```
awk -F/ '                                       # split records on "/"
!seen[$1] {                                     # the word is new (not seen)
    seen[$1]++                                  # remember the word as seen
    if ($2 != "") tags[$1] = $2                 # store the tag if not empty
    next                                        # skip to the next input
}
index(tags[$1], $2) == 0 && $2 != "" {          # if a new tag is input
    split(tags[$1], a, /,/)                     # split the string into an array
    tags[$1] = $2                               # redefine the string of tags
    for (i in a) {                              # loop over the stored tags
        if (index($2, a[i]) == 0)               # skip redundant tags
            tags[$1] = tags[$1] "," a[i]        # reconstruct the string of tags
    }
}
END {                                           # final output
    for (i in seen) {                           # loop over the words
        if (tags[i] == "") print i              # if the tag is empty, print just the word
        else {                                  # else print the word with each tag
            split(tags[i], a, /,/)
            for (j in a) {
                print i "/" a[j]
            }
        }
    }
}
' t1.txt
```

t1.txt:

```
test/e
this/x
word/p
and
some
more/qn
test
this
and
some
more/n
word/n
```

Output:

```
some
more/qn
this/x
and
word/n
word/p
test/e
```

**[Edit3]**
If you want to merge the tags for the same word, would you please try:

```
awk -F/ '                                       # split records on "/"
!seen[$1] {                                     # the word is new (not seen)
    seen[$1]++                                  # remember the word as seen
    if ($2 != "") tags[$1] = $2                 # store the tag if not empty
    next                                        # skip to the next input
}
$2 != "" {                                      # if a new tag(s) are input
    split($2, a, //)                            # break it to each tag
    for (i in a) {
        if (index(tags[$1], a[i]) == 0) {       # if the tag is new
            tags[$1] = tags[$1] a[i]            # then append it to the tag list
        }
    }
}
END {                                           # final output
    for (i in seen) {                           # loop over the words
        if (tags[i] == "") print i              # if the tag is empty, print just the word
        else print i "/" tags[i]                # else print the word with tags
    }
}
' t1.txt
```

t1.txt:

```
test/e
this/x
word/p
and
some
more/qn
test
this
and
some
more/n
word/n
abcd/p
abcd/np
```

Output:

```
some
abcd/pn
more/qn
this/x
and
word/pn
test/e
```

Comment: Is there any way to return 2 words "word" and "more" from the above output? (Because they are duplicated)

Comment: I've updated my answer with another awk command. Hope it will meet your requirement.

Comment: The user has sent an updated file with "more/qn" instead of "more/q". This has made the "more/n" entry redundant. I need the same output without "more/n". Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get the logic so far. Why `more/qn` makes `more/n` redundant? Is it because the character `n` is included in the set of `q` and `n`?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: I've updated my answer as `Edit2`. Hope it will meet your requirement. This is a quick hack and may have room for improvement/simplification. BR.

Comment: awesome! Thanks for your help. It is working as expected.

Comment: Instead of 2 entries for the word "word", is it possible to create a single entry word/np or word/pn? 50 points bounty as an appreciation of all your help.

Comment: Duly noted. As I'm out now, would you please allow me several hours to answer? BR

Comment: Yes. Bounty is for the help that you have already provided. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer as `Edit3`. Hope it will meet the requirement. BR.

Comment: This is correct. Can I get unique tags? For e.g. in production I am getting abcd/pnp instead of abcd/pn

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I find the problem occurs if `abcd/np` comes after `abcd/p`. I've fixed it updating`Edit3`. BR.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F/ '
!($1 in map) || length($0) >= length(map[$1]) {
   map[$1] = $0
   rows[$0]
}
END {
   for (i in rows)
      print i
}' file

some
test/e
more/n
more/q
word/n
and
word/p
this/x
```

---

**Original Solution:** (Question was turned around after recent edit)

You may try this `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -F/ '!seen[$1]++{
   rows[$0]
}
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
   for (i in rows)
      print i
}' file

and
more/q
some
test/e
this/x
word/p
```

---

If you don't have `gnu awk` then `PROCINFO` won't work, then you can use this `awk + sort` pipeline:

```
awk -F/ '!seen[$1]++{rows[$0]} END {for (i in rows) print i}' file |
sort
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and sort):

```
sort -u file | sed -E 'N;/^(.*)\n\1/!P;D'
```

Sort the file.

Append the next line.

If the first line is contained within the second, do not print it.

Otherwise print/delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: good idea! need to check for `/` after the backreference, otherwise partial matches like `some` and `somemore` will be falsely matched

Comment: @Sundeep thanks but this would prevent two occurrences of `some` collapsing to one. However anchoring the second line by a word ending might fit the bill.

Comment: You could use `sort -u` to remove exact duplicates

Comment: When I type "some" and "somemore" the word "some" is not selected as correctly pointed out by Sundeep. Therefore this answer is not correct.